# error Line 923: Char 34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++

This is my code. I am getting runtime error while running it on leetcode so help me  out.

I have tried all the already answers question of similar type but my code did not work. converted unsigned to int and ensured the vector is not empty.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> corpFlightBookings(vector<vector<int>>& bookings, int n) {
        vector<int> seats(0,n);
        int a = bookings.size();
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
            int c=bookings[i][0], d=bookings[i][1];
            for(int j=c;j<=d;j++){
                seats[j-1]=bookings[i][2]+seats[j-1];
            }
        }
        return seats;
    }
};
```

Line 923: Char 34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)
 I am getting this error

Comment: I'd suggest adding some `assert`s to verify your assumptions.

Comment: Also considering adding a space between two or more right angle brackets, like this: `vector< vector<int> >& bookings`. Otherwise some compilers will complaint.

Answer (score 4):

`vector<int> seats(0,n);` creates a vector of size zero (an empty vector), with all elements initialized to the value `n` (which is moot, as there are no elements). Then `seats[j-1]` exhibits undefined behavior, for any value of `j`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

You probably meant to pass arguments in reverse order, as in `vector<int> seats(n, 0);` This creates a vector of `n` elements, initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

vector<vector>& bookings may have size zero(or null).
So add below condition at the beginning of the code:

```
if(bookings.size()==0)
{
  ...
}
```

and then the left code.

Comment: This is not necessary, the loop will not run if the size of the `bookings` vector is 0. However, OP needs to consider whether it is valid to return `seats`, in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar kind of problem
I just added like if size of vector is zero then return "";
eg-

```
enter code here
int a = bookings.size();
if(a==0)
{
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to initialize a vector with default value in C++ is :

```
vector<int> vector_name(vector_size, default_value);
```

You just have a typo.